# How to calculate hover area by rectangles inside rectangle?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, language-agnostic

I have one rectangle of known dimensions ( for example 400 x 300 ) and arbitrary number of smaller rectangles inside ( inner rectangles have same width but smaller height or same height but smaller width ) and I have coordinates of corners of every inner rectangle. I need to calculate percentage of area cover with inner rectangles ( red on image ). Does anyone have any idea how to do this ?
( At the moment I first glue all horizontal and calculate area of those and then go from upper to lower and calculate only vertical parts to first horizontal and then jump through that and add area between next horizontals, it works but it is slow, is there any improvement possible )

Is there any algorithm for this ?[image]

Comment: language tag spam removed.

Answer (score 1):

The classic book *Computational Geometry: An Introduction* by Preparata and Shamos contains a chapter on rectangles that covers this in the general case.

Your problem seems much simpler: just decompose all rectangles into non-overlapping ones. Brute force should do it nicely. I don't know why you say it's slow.